# Apache Storm (Java): Bolt not receiving tuple from other Bolt

Tags: java, apache, apache-storm

I'm working with Apache Storm with this topology:

```
 TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();   
    builder.setSpout("socketspout", new SocketSpout(IP_HOST,PORT));
    builder.setBolt("filterone", new FilterOne()).shuffleGrouping("socketspout");
    builder.setBolt("filtertwo", new FilterTwo()).shuffleGrouping("filterone");
```

The methods of the first bolt are (FilteOne), this class extends BaseRichBolt:

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("ID1","signal1"));
}

 public void execute(Tuple input) {
    int sig;
    try {
        sig=input.getInteger(1)*2;
        System.out.println("Filter one.."+Integer.toString(sig));
        collector.emit("ack1", new Values(input.getString(0), sig));
        collector.ack(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        collector.fail(input);
    }
}
```

The methods of the second bolt are (FilteTwo), this class extends BaseRichBolt too:

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
}

 public void execute(Tuple input) {
    int sig;
    try {
        sig=input.getInteger(1)+1;
        System.out.println("Filter two.."+Integer.toString(sig));
        collector.ack(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        collector.fail(input);
    }
}
```

When execute the program mode localcluster I can see the first bolt emit the tuple but the second never receive the tuple......

[image]

Comment: The problem was solved modifying  the filter one code from
`collector.emit("ack1", new Values(input.getString(0), sig));`
to `collector.emit( new Values(input.getString(0), sig));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved modifying the filter one code from `collector.emit("ack1", new Values(input.getString(0), sig));` 
to `collector.emit( new Values(input.getString(0), sig));`

Answer (score 0):

The method emit's collector could set up as like:

```
collector.emit(input, new Values(input.getString(0), sig));
```

don't forget set the field name for this value, in method declareOutputFields:

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("myValue"));
    }
```

Then, in the second bolt, try to get the value using "myValue" field:

```
sig = input.getValueByField("myValue").getInteger(1)+1;
```